# How to concat two lists in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I was reading a prolog code about concatenation of two lists.
It works well but I cannot understand how it works :

```
concatenation([ ], Lista, Lista).
concatenation([ Elem | Lista1], Lista2, [Elem | Lista3]):-
                                     concatenation(Lista1, Lista2, Lista3).
?-concatenation([one, two], [three, four],L).
**Result : [one,two,three,four]**
```

First I cannot understand that in the goal part we have

```
**concatena([ Elem | Lista1], Lista2, [Elem | Lista3])**
```

I really cannot understand why instead of putting a normal variable and then handling the other calculations in the right side of ":-", it is starting to get the head and tail in the Goal part!

The second question is that how this recursion can give the next element of each lists in each iteration?

So my question is that how this algorithm works step by step.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I find that it helps me to read Prolog from Right To Left (which I guess is natural from both our native tongues anyway, I guess).

So the first part says:

```
concatenation([ ], Lista, Lista).
```

or: regardless of anything (the right-hand-side is empty), you can always concatenate an empty list to some list to obtain the same list.

Now the second part says, starting from the right,

```
concatenation(Lista1, Lista2, Lista3)
```

meaning you can concatenate `Lista1` to `Lista2`, obtaining `Lista3`.

and then the entire second part says

```
concatenation([ Elem | Lista1], Lista2, [Elem | Lista3]):-
    concatenation(Lista1, Lista2, Lista3).
```

meaning: if you can concatenate `Lista1` to `Lista2`, obtaining `Lista3`, then you can concatenate `Lista1` prepended by `Elem` to `Lista2`, obtaining `Lista3` prepended by `Elem`.

Comment: Yes. But then we have [Elem | Lista3]. Also it is a recursive code. How this recursion lead to iterate through the elements of the list?

Comment: Also,I cannot understand. The LEFT SIDE is just a function and we should do all the calculations in the RIGHT SIDE. It means in the left side we just need some Variables and in the right side we need to right a code to satisfy the goal.